# If i want to access certain comments in a file which have specific words below them. How do i do that?

Tags: python, file, comments

Basically i want to compare three sets of lists to another file. These lists are differentiated by comments. How do i compare it to each of these lists? DO i need to make three separate files for these lists?

example: Words have prefixes roots and suffixes. Example would be contradict. the prefix is con, the suffix is dict. I have a list of these prefix, suffixes etc. I need to know how to compare that list to the pile of words and basically count the number of roots,prefixes ad suffixes that exist in that file.

Comment: Could you edit the question to include an example,.

Comment: 'its done. I edited the question

Comment: It is up to you how you design it, all lists of words could be stored in one file. It would just need to have some kind of section delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

The following might help to get you started. It uses Python's `ConfigParser` to load a file which contains all of your lists. This file needs to be formatted as follows:

**vocab.txt**

```
[prefixes]
inter
con
mis

[roots]
cred
duct
equ

[suffixes]
dict
ment
ible
```

Each list of words gets loaded into the variables `prefixes`, `roots` and `suffixes` accordingly (with any duplicates removed). It then loads a source file called `input.txt` and splits this into a list of words called `words`. Each word is lowercased to make sure it matches one of the prefixes, roots or suffixes.

For each word a simple test is made to see if it matches any of your lists. Each match is displayed a counted. A total for each is also kept and displayed at the end.

```
import ConfigParser
import re

vocab = ConfigParser.ConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
vocab.read('vocab.txt')

def get_section(section):
    return set(v[0].lower() for v in vocab.items(section))

prefixes = get_section('prefixes')
roots = get_section('roots')
suffixes = get_section('suffixes')

total_prefixes = 0
total_roots = 0
total_suffixes = 0

with open('input.txt', 'r') as f_input:
    text = f_input.read()
    words = [word.lower() for word in re.findall('\w+', text)]

    for word in words:
        word_prefixes = [p for p in prefixes if word.startswith(p)]
        total_prefixes += len(word_prefixes)

        word_roots = [r for r in roots if r in word[1:]]
        total_roots += len(word_roots)

        word_suffixes = [s for s in suffixes if word.endswith(s)]
        total_suffixes += len(word_suffixes)

        print '{:15}  Prefixes {}  {}, Roots {} {}, Suffixes {} {}' .format(word,
            len(word_prefixes), word_prefixes, len(word_roots), word_roots, len(word_suffixes), word_suffixes)

print
print 'Totals:\n  Prefixes {}, Roots {}, Suffixes {}'.format(total_prefixes, total_roots, total_suffixes)
```